# Please how can I take Snapshots of Tables daily coming from a a Marketing Platform using Snowflake

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, storage, snapshot

I am trying to take Snapshots of Data Daily coming from a Marketing Platform used by the company I work for. I have tried Snowflake Time Travel but doesnt seem to solve the issue, are there any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the issue that Time Travel is not solving? What’s the purpose for taking snapshots (i.e. what’s the business requirement that you think creating snapshots would be the solution to)?

Comment: Please elaborate on the requirement. It could involve cloning, streams, both or neither.

Comment: Another feature is called cloning that may be of interest: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/cloning-in-snowflake